# Changed JAVA_HOME to 1.8, but java -version points to 1.7

Tags: java

I set JAVA_HOME to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle` in `~/.bashrc`.

```
root@gosper-HP-EliteBook:/home/gosper# echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

However when I run `java -version` it points to `java version "1.7.0_80"` instead of `1.8`.

```
root@gosper-HP-EliteBook:/home/gosper# java -version
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
```

What am I doing wrong? How to upgrade to 1.8?

UPDATE:

```
root@gosper-HP-EliteBook:/home/gosper# type -a java
java is /usr/bin/java
java is /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
java is /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
java is /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
java is /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java


root@gosper-HP-EliteBook:/home/gosper# whereis  java
java: /usr/bin/java /usr/bin/X11/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
```

Comment: please check you env setup of the ECLIPSE; I already heard that in you other post

Comment: @victor sosa: you are absolutely right. though it does not relate to this thread, I should say that changing JRE settings in Eclipse solved all the problem (Window->Preferences->Server->Edit Tomcat 8->JRE - 1.8). I accepted the answer of SMA because it helped resolve the issue explained in this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have path variable pointing to JDK7. For the current session, you could re mediate it like below:

```
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

If you want to fix it permanently, then make an entry of path in .bashrc.

Answer (score 0):

You  may have a symbolic link on /usr/bin (or in other path folder) pointing to old java installation.

Or a direct declaration in  the path.

Answer (score 0):

please  share with  us :

```
type -a java 
whereis  java
```

in order  to undestand what  is going on. Share  with us the console output please.

UPDATE your link like this :

```
ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java /usr/bin/java
```